# Percorrer campos input ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

```js
/* Retorna produtos banco de dados */
    $scope.produtos = [];
    var carregaProduto = function () {
        $http.get("app/models/retornaProduto.php").then(function (response) {
            $scope.produtos = response.data;
        });
    };
    carregaProduto();
    
    /* Calcula valor produtos */
    $scope.multiplicaValor = function (index) {

        index.totalLinha = index.produtoQtd * index.produtoPreco;
        $scope.soma = 0;
        $scope.giga = 0;
        $scope.linha = 0;
        $scope.id = index.produtoId;
        $scope.ids = index.produtoQtd;

        angular.forEach($scope.produtos, function (value, key) {
            $scope.soma += value.produtoQtd * value.produtoPreco;
            $scope.giga += value.produtoQtd * value.produtoGB;
            if (value.produtoQtd > 0) {
                $scope.linha += (value.produtoQtd * value.produtoQtd) / value.produtoQtd;
            }
        });
    }
```

boa noite! Preciso percorrer os input preenchidos e exibir em uma modal (Quero Contratar?

```html
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-3 mb-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Mais Informações</button>
<a ui-sref="simulaVivo" class="btn btn-sm mt-3 mb-2 ml-5" style="background: #932399;color: #FFF;">
    <i class="fa fa-binoculars"></i>&nbsp; Ver Planos Vivo</a>
<a ui-sref="simulaTim" class="btn btn-sm mt-3 mb-2" style="background: #004691;color: #FFF">
    <i class="fa fa-binoculars"></i>&nbsp; Ver Planos Tim</a>
<a ui-sref="comparaPlanos" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mt-3 mb-2">
    <i class="fa fa-balance-scale"></i>&nbsp; Comparar Planos</a>
<form name="formSimula" class="mb-4">
    <div class="card mt-2 sticky-top">
        <div class="card-header font-weight-bold" style="background: rgba(254,187,112,.4); border: 2px solid rgba(254,187,112,.5)">
            <img src="app/dist/images/icon-claro.png">
            <div class="float-right align-middle" ng-show="soma > 0" style="font-size: 30px; color: #2d1b53">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mr-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#queroContratar"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Quero Contratar!</button>
                <span>
                    <i class="fa fa-phone" style="font-size: 24px"></i> {{linha}}</span>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
                <span>{{giga}} GB</span>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
                <span>{{soma | currency}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="claro in produtos | filter:{produtoOperadora:'Claro'}">
            <div class="card mt-2 mb-2" style="box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #999">
                <div class="box-item-oferta-1" ng-if="claro.produtoOferta == 1">
                    <span class="label label-important font-fira">
                        <i class="fa fa-tags"></i> OFERTA</span>
                </div>

                <div class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold color-amarelo" style="font-size: 1.5em; background: #2d1b53">
                    {{claro.produtoGB}} GB - {{ claro.produtoPreco | currency}}
                    <p class="color-amarelo mb-0" style="font-size: 11px;">valor por linha</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="font14 font-weight-bold">Qtd</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center font-weight-bold" ng-model="claro.produtoQtd" ng-change="multiplicaValor(claro)"
                                style="font-size: 1.125em" value="{{claro.produtoId}}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="font14 font-weight-bold">Total</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center font-weight-bold" disabled style="font-size: 1.125em"
                                value="{{claro.totalLinha | currency}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="card-text mt-3 font13" style="font-weight: 600">{{claro.produtoDesc}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="queroContratar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title text-danger" id="exampleModalLabel">
                                <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Quero Contratar</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title text-danger">
                    <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Informações Conteúdo Digital</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="app/dist/images/conteudo-digital.png" width="100%">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

). Exemplo tenho 8 campos e foram preenchidos somente 2 campos..eu gostaria de exibir somente os campos preenchidos na modal para gerar uma proposta. Eu faço isso com forEach? Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo. Os campos veem do ng-repeat como percorrer os preenchidos? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem como colocar o exemplo minimo ???

Comment: Tem um botão na página Quero Contratar que abre uma modal..eu preciso percorrer os campos preenchidos na Qtd e passar para essa modal. No exemplo da imagem está preenchido o campo 30GB e o campo 10GB gostaria de passar esses dois valores para o modal. Isso que não estou conseguindo fazer. Faço com forEach para percorrer os campos preenchidos?

Comment: Ricardo eu preciso ver o seu código do Angular!? eu não sei da onde está vindo os dados!

Comment: Foi mal...iniciante!

Comment: Você só quer o dado filtrado para jogar um `ng-repeat` no modal?

Comment: Sim somente os que tiveram o campo preenchido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um exemplos minimo onde e executado um filtro no `array` da seguinte forma:

```
$scope.produtos.filter(function(it){
  return (it.Quant > 0);
});
```

Exemplo completo:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('indexCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.produtos = [{
      'Name': 'Arroz',
      'Quant': '',
      'Valor': ''
    },
    {
      'Name': 'Feijão',
      'Quant': '',
      'Valor': ''
    },
    {
      'Name': 'Café',
      'Quant': '',
      'Valor': ''
    }
  ];
  $scope.filterProdutos = function(){
    var items = $scope.produtos.filter(function(it){
      return (it.Quant > 0);
    });
    console.log(items);
    return items;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="indexCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="p in produtos">
    <labe>{{p.name}}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="p.Quant" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="p.Valor" />
  </div>
  <button ng-click="filterProdutos()">Filtrar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: na modal não exibe os dados

Comment: @RicardoChomics você escreveu o ngRepeat naquelas tag li!?

Comment: tinha esquecido agora deu certo, valeu mais uma vez